# GET request with "If-Match" and ETags

Tags: http, rest, http-headers, etag, http-caching

I'm working on implmenenting ETag functionality for a RESTful service, and I'd like to be as close to the HTTP spec as possible. The spec however is not as clear as it probably should be. Specifically:

**The `If-Match` header - what are it's semantics for a GET request?**

Presumably, a GET with the `If-Match` header will, if the value is **matched** with the value of the ETag - return the actual Resource with *200 OK* (not 304). 
If the value is **not matched**, a *412 Precondition Failed* should be returned, along with the new value of the ETag and no content?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080718/correct-behavior-with-if-match-the-header

Comment: please see whether http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p4-conditional-21.html answers your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's correct, expect that the new value of the `ETag` on a 412 response to a `If-Match` is [nowhere](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.24) required by the spec. You can omit it. It's only [recommended](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.26) on a 304 response to a `If-None-Match`. Perhaps that's where your confusion was caused.